# Using jakarta instead of javax gives the error javax.servlet.jsp cannot be resolved to a type when using ${pageContext.response.locale} in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, jakarta-migration

Recently I started migrating my Spring Framework MVC project to Tomcat 10 and Jakarta and while doing this I am stuck with 1 strange error.
In my JSP file I usually had the following code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

    <c:set var="localeCode" value="${pageContext.response.locale}" />
```

Well Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) gives me the error on this file "**javax.servlet.jsp cannot be resolved to a type**".

I tried everything I could think off and now do not know how to proceed. When I remove the "**${pageContext.response.locale}**" part from the JSP the error disappears.

Any ideas what could be the case?

In my MAVEN pom file I have the following:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.el-api</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                 <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
                 <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
                 <version>3.0.2</version>
             </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Please share your codebase via github

Comment: As well as which versions of Eclipse and STS you were using when you imported this project into the workspace.

Comment: What is the actual version of JSP used at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

After adding a pom update The error marker was gone:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        </dependency>
```

The final pom looked like this:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>5.3.28</spring.version>
        <security.version>5.5.0</security.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>       
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version> <!-- Jakarta EE 9 version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version> <!-- Use the appropriate version -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.5.Final</version> 
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version> 
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```